# LEFT JOIN not working as expected with sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I've got the SQL query below:

```
SELECT message, sent_date, user_id
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN numbers ON messages.from_id = numbers.id
```

It returns all the rows (about 4000) in the `messages` table with additional columns coming from the `numbers` table. So far, this is what I would expect.

Now I left join this sub-query to another table, again using a left join:

```
SELECT message, sent_date
FROM (
    SELECT message, sent_date, user_id
    FROM messages
    LEFT JOIN numbers ON messages.from_id = numbers.id
) AS table1
LEFT JOIN users ON table1.user_id = users.id
```

However, it only returns about 200 rows so many are missing. Since this is a left join I would expect all the rows from table1 to be in the result. Can anybody see what the issue is?

**Edit:**

So for information here are the 3 relevant tables (with irrelevant columns removed):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from_id` (`from_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=101553 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `numbers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6408 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2395 ;
```

Comment: Is `user_id` in table `messages`?

Comment: Do you have `WHERE` in the last query that you didn't include in the question?

Comment: Is it possible that in between some other connection deleted or updated some rows from table?

Comment: @ypercube, user_id is in the table `numbers`.

Comment: @ypercube, no `WHERE` in the last query.

Comment: Do you have same behaviour if you change the internal select to: `SELECT message, sent_date, numbers.user_id`?

Comment: @ypercube, I've just tried this but still the same number of results. I still cannot make sense of this query results. In case it helps, I've added the 3 relevant tables to the main post.

Comment: Which (exact) version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: @ypercube, it's version 5.5.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: I think you are either doing something wrong or you have a hit a bug. Can you test or upgrade in a newer version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try alternative method to debug the issue:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table tmp1 AS SELECT message, sent_date, user_id
                               FROM messages
                                    LEFT JOIN numbers 
                                        ON messages. from_id = numbers.id;
```

and then see whether this query works.

```
 SELECT message, sent_date
 FROM tmp1 table1
      LEFT JOIN users 
          ON table1.user_id = users.id;
```

Also for your case make sure that there are no other insert or updates in between. otherwise use transactions.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed working. Athough I'd be curious to know why the equivalent query, with subquery, doesn't work?

Comment: And the original still doesn't work? Are you sure you have not set accidentally a limit (200) on the result set?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>table1 sometimes won't have a UserID - so that'll be null, so those results will be missing?</strike>

Comment: `user_id` is indeed sometime null, but since table1 is on the left, shouldn't all its results be included? If not, how can the query be fixed?

Comment: Actually, I'm talking rubbish. Do you have a result limit set on your query window?

Comment: @podiluska: I think you are right, the most probbale cause is a result limit. @Laurent, what is the result if you replace the `SELECT message, sent_date FROM (...` with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it's a scoping issue on `user_id`.

```
SELECT table1.message, table1.sent_date 
FROM ( 
    SELECT messages.message, messages.sent_date, numbers.user_id 
    FROM messages 
    LEFT JOIN numbers ON messages.from_id = numbers.id 
) AS table1 
LEFT JOIN users ON table1.user_id = users.id
```

I'm not sure if `user_id` is in `messages` or `numbers`.

Comment: It also only returns 200 results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer to your question, but if I have to start thinking, I will first find out what 3800 rows are missing and try to see the pattern (is it because user_id are null or duplicate)

```
SELECT message, sent_date, user_id
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN numbers ON messages.from_id = numbers.id
MINUS
(SELECT table1.message, table1.sent_date, table1.user_id
FROM (
    SELECT message, sent_date, user_id
    FROM messages
    LEFT JOIN numbers ON messages.from_id = numbers.id
) AS table1
LEFT JOIN users ON table1.user_id = users.id)
```

Comment: I can't quite see any pattern. There are duplicate user_id in the final results because one user can send more than one message, there are also NULL user_id, it seems quite random to me. The query seems to include or exclude results without any particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way this should happen.

Try this variation:

```
SELECT 
    m.message, m.sent_date, n.user_id
FROM
    messages m
  LEFT JOIN 
    numbers AS n  ON m.from_id = n.id
  LEFT JOIN 
    users AS u  ON n.user_id = u.id ;
```